# Setting values in a table from another table

Tags: java, sql

What would be the correct way to write this query?

```
String squery= "update Room set GuestCode="+gc+", FirstName=(select FirstName from GuestDetails where GuestCode="+gc+"), LastName=(select LastName from GuestDetails where GuestCode="+gc+"), Country=(select Country from GuestDetails where GuestCode="+gc+"), State=(select State from GuestDetails where GuestCode="+gc+"), City=(select City from GuestDetails where GuestCode="+gc+"), ContactNo=(select ContactNo from GuestDetails where GuestCode="+gc+") where RoomNo="+rn+"";
```

i am trying to set some values in a table(Room) from another table(GuestDetails) with guestcode as input. I am getting an exception as invalid memo, ole, or hyperlink object in subquery. Please help.

Comment: What is that `()` in your query between the assignments for `City` and `ContactNo` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be a ',' there. It may have got added while pasting it.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate or just jdbc? + First of all, always use bindings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a Better way of writing your update. This works in sql server

```
UPDATE A
SET    GuestCode = 'gc',
       FirstName = B.FirstName,
       LastName = B.LastName,
       Country = Country,
       State = B.State,
       City = B.City,
       ContactNo = B.contactNO
FROM   ROOM A
       JOIN GuestDetails B
         ON b.GuestCode = 'gc'
WHERE  RoomNo = 'rn';
```

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use a stored procedure to avoid sql injection. Your code is vers vulnerable for injection.

Also use a join to avoid sub-selects due to performance issues.

Comment: *Its better to use a stored procedure to avoid sql injection*: This is not entirely true. The simplest solution is to use a instance of `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Yes indeed it is true. Use parameters instead of hard coding the code.